# Let $F(x,y,z)= f(x^2-y^2,2x-y+z)$ with $f$ differentiable find $\nabla F(1,2,3)$ using the chain rule

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis, chain-rule

> Let $F(x,y,z)= f(x^2-y^2+z,2x-y+z)$ with $f: \mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R$ differentiable
>
> a)Suppose $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(0,3)=-2$,  $\frac{\partial F}{\partial w}(0,3)=1$ with $v=(1,1)$ and    $w=(1,-2).$ Find  $\nabla (0,3).$
>
> b)Using the chain rule find $\nabla F(1,2,3)$
>
> c) Find the tangent plane to Gr(F) in $(c, F(c))$ with c=(1,2,3)

Using the equivalence between directional derivates and the differential I got $\nabla f(0,3)=(-1,-1)$

My problem is how to solve b), I'm confused and don't know how to use the chain rule. My aproach:

Let $h(x,y,z)=(x^2-y^2+z,2x-y+z)$ then $$D F(1,2,3) = D(f\circ h)(1,2,3)$$ $$= Df(h(1,2,3)) \circ Dh(1,2,3)$$
$$=Df(0,3) \circ D h(1,2,3)$$

And $$Dh(1,2,3)=
\begin{bmatrix}
2x& -2y & 1\\
2& -1 & 1
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
2& -4 & 1\\
2& -1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

thus $\nabla F(1,2,3)= (-4,5,-2)$ Is it right?

Comment: There is an error in the problem. How did you get the extra $z$ term in $h$?

Comment: Thanks , I`ve corrected the problem

Comment: Try that matrix multiplication again.

Comment: Is it correct now?